# htaccess Rewrite code for specific pages

Tags: .htaccess

I am using this Rewrite rule in my `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?page_slug=$1 [L, QSA]
```

how can i also redirect `domain.com/online-shop/` to `domain.com/online-shop/home` the same way as above?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a new rule for that specific page:

```
RewriteRule ^(online-shop)/?$ /$1/home [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!online-shop/)[\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?page_slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: i just want `online-shop` to show/redirect to `online-shop/home`

Comment: If you don't want URL to change then then remove `R=302` from first rule.

Comment: why have you put two different rules in?

Comment: One is your already existing rule and 2nd is the one needed by your requirement.